# strtotime() doesn't return false

Tags: php, strtotime

`strtotime(" ")` doesn't return false when I provide string containing just space or any other character.

Are there any less code solutions to make it return false?

I can't use `preg_match`, because date formats are all different depending on locale of each user.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

> Returns a timestamp on success, FALSE otherwise. Previous to PHP
>   5.1.0, this function would return -1 on failure.

**Edit: I need to validate the date string, not to trim spaces or other user-provided characters.**

Comment: @AlexG Trim only strips from the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Guys, I don't need to remove the space, I need to validate the date string. See my edit.

Comment: Fwiw, trimming itself is not a goal, it's just a helpful operation to prevent passing a whitespace-only argument to `strtotime()`.

Comment: `strtotime` should return false if it's not a valid format, why to help it with `trim()` ?

Comment: If you your goal is not to solve a specific task, and you are considering the function behavior as a bug, then [reporting a PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/) would probably make sense instead of asking here. It's actually already [reported](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66486) on 2014-01-15.

Comment: @MaratTanalin: reasonable, just wanted to confirm that there is nothing I do wrong here. I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `trim()` as a workaround to remove leading and trailing whitespace before calling `strtotime()`.

`strtotime(' ')` returns current time.

`strtotime('')` (`strtotime(trim(' '))`) returns `false`.

This behavior of the function is already [reported](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66486) as a bug and has a [fix](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/615) based on trimming, but it looks like the patch has not yet been accepted by the PHP team for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?  Have you tried removing the space?  Is there a good reason to keep the space?  I get false when no space is present.

strtotime("")

Comment: A space returns the current time...the current time is a value so it is true.  No space returns false...it's just how PHP is written.